# Select row/Section of on a collectionView or TableView where cell label equals a given string?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

Is it possible to select a row or a section of a uitableview / uicollection views label is equal to a particular string.

so as an example

```
let array = ["a","b","c","d","e"]

cell.textlabel.text = array[indexPath.row]
```

I then select rows 0,1,4 and add them to a saved array

```
let savedArray = ["a", "b", "e"]
```

I know I could save the indexPath and add it to a dictionary and then call it that way but what if the array changes to

```
 let array = ["a","f","b","c","d","e"]
```

I would then not be selecting the right rows.

Thus what I want to do is search the cells.titleLabels.text and if it matches then programatically select it.

**so my question is how do I search the cells.titleLabel?**

thanks in advance

Comment: You mean when you come next time you want to select the cell that was previously selected ?

Comment: That's basically what I want yes. The collection view has sections and rows

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question!  If the question becomes, how do I track state for my tableView, then you could look at storing the data in a struct / class containing the label text and also selection state.  Then if anything changes you can reload individual rows or the whole table, and set the cell state depending on the data - not based on what you already have in the temporary controls on the reusableTableViewCell

Comment: @Tom Is  your collectionView set view multiple selection?

Comment: yes @NiravD the collection view is set to multiple selections

Comment: Check out my answer below - tell me if it answers your question

Comment: thanks ill try and give it a go now

Comment: @Tom Is my solution works for you?

Comment: Hi Nirav, I tried salil juniors answer but was getting strange behaviour. So gave up last night as it was getting late. I will try your solution a little later today

Comment: Nirav's solution and my solution is pretty much the same thing - only difference is how we are checking if your savedArray has value for current cell. Instead of saying "strange behaviour" why not comment on the answer and ask for further clarification?

Comment: Think I might have downed the answer by mistake? Won't let me rectify but I'll try it again shortly sorry

Comment: @Tom You haven't respond is it working now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the object value in `cellForItemAt` method.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { 
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textlabel.text = array[indexPath.row]
    cell.isSelected = savedArray.contains(array[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your `cellForIndexAt:` CollectionView delegate method (where you set up the cell) you can set a condition to check if the current data item for the given cell is in your `savedArray` - and if so, you can the set the selected state for that cell.

so something like:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)
        // iterate through saved array and see if your current item is in it
    let savedItems = savedArray.Filter({ item -> Bool in
        return item == array[indexPath.row] // this shall return true if item for current cell is in the saved array OR you could do any kind of logical comparison here e.g. item == "random string" 
   })

   if(savedItems.count > 0) {
      // here set the selected state of cell as you wish 
  }

        return cell
    }
```

Hope this helps.